# "Unable to reach app. Please try again" on Adaptive card

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams, azure-bot-service

I am using bot framework SDK in Python for Teams channel .

Bot showing "Unable to reach app. Please try again"  in adaptive card even my whole process is completed successfully and I got back the responses properly.

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y9J7G.png)

I also go through https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-howto-long-operations-guidance?view=azure-bot-service-4.0 this but not proper solution in python .

i want solution like ..
can I disable the this 10 or 15 second timeout on action button ?
OR
Is there any other way to increase this 15 sec timeout time ?
OR
Is there any way action button wait for response on behalf of sending error message ?

Comment: There is a 10 or 15 second timeout that can occur, and if it does then I think that would cause what you're seeing.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to disable or otherwise alter the service timeout. That is a function of the Botframework (aka Azure Bot Service) Connector which manages the traffic between the various channels/clients and any bots. In order to avoid service timeout errors, you must have your bot respond within this time frame.

That being said, if you have a "long running operation", the answer is to use a proactive message (doc ref [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-howto-proactive-message?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=python)) which is mentioned in the link you provided. You can also find a working Python sample in the BotFramework-Samples repo located [here](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/main/samples/javascript_nodejs/16.proactive-messages).

In short, if you know pressing the adaptive card button is going to result in a long running operation, then simply have the bot return a generic response, like "One moment while I retrieve that for you". Meanwhile, the long running process will be working and, once the data is available, you use a proactive message to send the data to the user.